# Create a generic angular resource action for more entities

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using angular resource with different entities and I have to call, for each of these entities, some custom methods with custom urls.

For example:

```
var actions = { 
    create: {
        method: 'POST'
    },
    customMethod: {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/api/entity1/:id/custom',
        params: {
            id: '@id'
        },
    }
}
$resource('/api/entity1/:id', null, actions);
$resource('/api/entity2/:id', null, actions);
$resource('/api/entity3/:id', null, actions);
```

In this way, obviusly, customMethod will work only on entity1 because the url is not generic.
How can I create a custom action without defining urls, as I did on create action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple variables when using $resource. replace

```
url: '/api/entity1/:id/custom'
```

with

```
url: '/api/:entity/:id/custom'
```

and use the appropriate params when calling the $resource function.

Comment: I don't like a solution where I have to call:

Resource.customMethod({ entity: 'resource', id: '7' }).

Answer (score 0):

Add an action param for custom method and url:

```
var actions = { 
  create: {
    method: 'POST'
  },
  customMethod: {
    method: 'PUT',
    params: { action: 'custom' },
  }
}
$resource('/api/entity1/:id/:action', null, actions);
$resource('/api/entity2/:id/:action', null, actions);
```